# Errors - Error The mysqli extension is missing. IIS Window 7 Even after INI Setting

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed PHP by XAMPP and installed MySQL on Windows 7 and IIS I could see well. Now when I tried installing phpMyAdmin I am getting following message "The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration." I have done the INI file setting for following

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=php_mysqli
extension=mysqli
;extension=php_mysql
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

Still there is an error

> phpMyAdmin - Error The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your
>   PHP configuration.

Comment: What does the output of phpinfo() say? You can create a file in your web root with the content `<?php phpinfo();` and call that through your browser to see the actual configuration being used by PHP to verify what extensions are loaded. Most likely, there's another configuration file taking precedence over your changes.

Comment: Wait a minute, phpMyAdmin should come with XAMPP, you shouldn't need to install it yourself — and mysqli should be configured by default on that system. Something strange is going on with your XAMPP installation, if you have no existing data in your database or web pages, I suggest completely reinstalling.